# Conditionally return a wrapped or base type

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript and I'm having a hard time find the right combination of keywords to search to figure this out. I think I need to use a type condition, but I don't quite understand how they work yet.

What I want to do is pass a function that does some sort of manipulation. If that function returns a specific type then I want to wrap it in a box, otherwise return the original value.

Take for example:

```js
class Box<T> {
    value: T;
    constructor(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
   }
}

function wrapIfString<T, TResult>(fn: (value: T) => TResult, value: T): 
   TResult extends string ? Box<string> : TResult {

   const result = fn(value);
   if (value instanceof String) {
       return new Box<string>(result);
   }

   return result;
}
```

But this doesn't compile. Is this something I can do in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.... Conditional return types can generally lead to problems like this where its more than likely cleaner just to overload like so...

```
class Box<T> {
    value: T;
    constructor(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
   }
}


function wrapIfString<T>(fn: (value: T) => string, value: T): Box<string>
function wrapIfString<T, TResult>(fn: (value: T) => TResult, value: T): TResult
function wrapIfString<T, TResult>(fn: (value: T) => TResult, value: T): TResult | Box<string> {
   const result = fn(value);
    if (value instanceof String && typeof result === "string") {
       return new Box<string>(result);
   }
   return result;
}


const testType = wrapIfString((n) => "", "hello") // Box<string>
const testType1 = wrapIfString((n) => n * n, 5) // number
```